# I nee to send current ( Latitude and Longitude and in time and out time and date ) to server using api get method how to

Tags: flutter, rest, flutter-dependencies, flutter-apk

Our Plan to view and Work the app like

[image]

First time user click the button the attendance Check in successfully and the **Chick in Button name to change Check Out .  **

and show the Alerts message.

our Api :

check in : `http://localhost/school/api/in-attendance/2?date=2023-11-30&in_time=11:00&lat=1&lng=2`

check Out : `http://localhost/school/api/out-attendance/2?date=2023-11-30&out_time=11:00&lat=1&lng=2`

Note : please Note the Id and In time and Out Time Prams

Comment: What's the question? And do you really mean 'localhost'? That implies the API server is running on the phone(!)

Comment: Host your local to the backend server and Implement the API integration .Use Dio or Http for Api request and response .